# r two conditional filter in a list

Tags: r, list

in a R list, I can use a logical condition as filter

```
> l <- 1:10
> l
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> l[l>3]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

how I can use two conditions ? like

```
l[l> 3 && l <8]
```

to get

```
> l[l>3 && l < 8]
[1]  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Just remove that second `&` as in `l[l> 3 & l <8]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks, you can add your comment as answer ?

Comment: I will just close this as a dupe if you don't mind.